# Filtering a very lengthy ListView

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listview, listviewitem

folks.

I'm working on a project for school, and I'm trying to figure out what the best method would be to solve a problem regarding the filtering/searching of entries in a ListView.

I've currently got a ListView control named `lvCard` that (at the time it needs to be filtered, after being populated from a JSON file on FormLoad) contains roughly 15000 entries.  It is a multi-column ListView (Detail view), which basically contains every Magic the Gathering card ever made.

I have a searchbox also present named `txtSearch`.

I understand that basically, I need to have some sort of functionality attached to the "changed" event of the search box, but after that, I'm sort of lost.

Currently, all I have is a subroutine I wrote that populates the target ListView when the application starts up, which I guess provides some insight as to how the target ListView is set up, but other than that, I'm really confused, and could use some guidance for sure.

```
' Render the whole list of stuff
Private Sub RenderList(dict As Dictionary(Of String, Card))

    ' Grab keys into list for sorting
    Dim lstCards As List(Of String) = dict.Keys.ToList
    lstCards.Sort()

    ' iteration
    Dim str As String
    For Each str In lstCards

        Dim CurrentCard As Card = dict(str)

        Dim CurrentPT As String
        If IsNumeric(CurrentCard.power) And IsNumeric(CurrentCard.toughness) Then
            CurrentPT = CurrentCard.power & "/" & CurrentCard.toughness
        Else
            CurrentPT = ""
        End If

        ' Build list item
        Dim CurrentItem As New ListViewItem(CurrentCard.name)
        CurrentItem.SubItems.Add(CurrentCard.manaCost)
        CurrentItem.SubItems.Add(CurrentCard.type)
        CurrentItem.SubItems.Add(CurrentPT)
        lvCard.Items.Add(CurrentItem)

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works as I have no way of testing it at the moment, and I don't know it is the most efficient way of doing it, but you could add another `ByVal` to your `RenderList` sub and then pass a search item to it like so:

```
Private Sub RenderList(ByVal dict As Dictionary(Of String, Card), ByVal Optional search As String = Nothing)
    If search Is Not Nothing Then
       'Grab SEARCHED keys into list for sorting

       'Populate the initial list first
        Dim lstCards As List(Of String) = dict.Keys.ToList

        'Create a new list to contain all found items
        Dim newLst As List(Of String)

        For Each item As String In lstCards
            If item.ToLower.Contains(search.ToLower) Then
                newLst.Add(item)
            End If
        Next

        'Set lstCards to the new list of items
        lstCards = newLst
        lstCards.Sort()
    Else
        'Grab ALL keys into list for sorting
        Dim lstCards As List(Of String) = dict.Keys.ToList
        lstCards.Sort()
    End If

    /.../

End Sub
```

And then use `RenderList(mycards, TextBox1.Text)` to your `TextBox1.TextChanged` event.